# How can i use only one function showCnt() to show the members of struct arrays? How to pass parameters?

Tags: c

I'm learning a piece of code, I don't know how to implement this function using only one function? How to pass parameters to the function?

```c
#include <stdio.h>

struct colleagues {
    int female[10];
    int male[10];
} teams[20];

void func(int count[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", count[i]);
    }
}

//FIXME
void showCnt(void (*function)(int *), int XXX[])
{
    for (int n = 0; n < 20; n++) {
        func(teams[n].XXX);
    }
}

int main()
{
    //How can i just use only one function showCnt to do this work???, I'm so appreciated.
    //***FIXME, How can i pass parameters "teams.female" to showCnt???***
    showCnt(function, teams.female);
    showCnt(function, teams.male);
    return 0;
}
```

Sorry, I didn't say it clearly. I don't know how to pass the parameters "teams.male" as a array to showCnt(), I'm wondering how to call showCnt() twice separately to print the info.

For example, first, It calls showCnt(teamXX.female), second, it calls showCnt(teamXXX.male). I don't know if I can pass parameters to showCnt() to make "func(team[n].male)" and "func(team[n].female)" working properly.

Comment: count is not an attribute of the colleagues struct.

Comment: On a personal comment, it seems you should take a few steps back, and start over with your text-book (and possibly get a couple of other ones). You seem to have some very basic misunderstandings about how arrays, structures and functions work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to only call `showCnt` as

```
showCnt(function);
```

and it should print both `teams.female` and `teams.male`?

Then to begin with remove the (*erroneous*) `count` argument from the function `showCnt`. Then inside the loop of `showCnt` call `function` *twice* with `teams[n].female` and `teams[n].male`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Sorry, I didn't say it clearly. I don't know how to pass the parameters "teams.male" as a array to showCnt(), I'm wondering how to call showCnt() twice separately to print the info. For example, first, It calls showCnt(teamXX.female), second, it calls showCnt(teamXXX.male). I don't know if I can pass parameters to showCnt() to make "func(team[n].male)" and "func(team[n].female)" working properly.

Comment: @Richard Then you need to have the loop over the array `teams` outside of the `showCnt` function. You need to passs a *specific* `male` or `female` array, and for that you need a *specific* element of `teams`.